# How to handle multiple video streams in Red5?

Tags: java, flash, video, red5, rtmp

I am writing a [Red5](http://www.red5.org/) application that provides 1-on-1 video chat to a Flash client over [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol).

Unfortunately most tutorials I was able to find were sketchy at best and the documentation of Red5 itself tends to be vague when it comes to API concepts and intended usage.

In short, I am a bit stuck and looking for hints on Red5 `ApplicationAdapter` implementation. Gnarly details are as follows:

- First of all, the connections come in two flavors: visitors and consultants. A visitor should be able to indicate which consultant it wishes to communicate with. A consultant simply gets connected to the requesting visitor as long as the consultant is not busy servicing another.
- Obviously, every RTMP connection has two-way traffic: both sending and receiving video. From the standpoint of the server, connections bring in a bunch of video streams that get their receiving endpoints assigned by request.
- Since several video conversations can be in progress simultaneously, the main task of the application is to handle the mapping of visitor streams to consultants and provide a list indicating each consultant's state (busy/available) via [AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format).

So, all in all, I have a pretty good idea what I am aiming for but how to achieve it with Red5 is still a bit of a mystery.

Hopefully someone can enlighten me in any or all of the following:

1. What is the easiest way to establish the connection type (visitor/consultant)?
2. Which API classes should be used to implement a persistent, globally accessible list of active connections for reporting the state of each consultant?
3. How to switch receving endpoints dynamically when the goal is to connect a specific visitor to the selected consultant?

Comment: These guys seem to have written up and documented something similar: http://www.red5chat.com/features-webcamchat.htm

Comment: @blueberryfields - red5chat hasn't been updated in over 2 years, and according to the comments on its sourceforge page, has horrible docs and isn't complete source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saul ,

> 1.What is the easiest way to establish
>   the connection type
>   (visitor/consultant)?

assuming that both(visitor/consultant) are using flex client via which they start publishing their live video stream ,here you need to make sure that each published video **stream name is unique** (HOWTO is already mentioned in demo apps)

> 2.Which API classes should be used to
>   implement a persistent, globally
>   accessible list of active connections
>   for reporting the state of each
>   consultant?

and for providing the list of active connections you simply need to store(preferably in your db) each user's id with the stream name (which is also available as a [tutorial demo app](http://www.red5tutorials.net/index.php/Tutorials%3aStreaming_and_database_connection_with_red5_media_server)) to connect to.

I believe all the code is available for the red5 demos Do try oflaDemo , simpleSubscriber , fitcDemo demo apps.

I hope I am closer to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since Oflademo or red5 is capable of 1v1 chats, then replicate this code to make around 50 chats. You can maintain a table with the following columns :

- chat room number (1 to 50)
- user1
- user2
- status(0 or 1 - unoccupied or occupied)

If let say a visitor V22 wants to get consulted from consultor C33, then a program can detect the first unoccupied room from 1 to 50, if the 7th room is unoccupied then, redirect V22 and C33 to room 7 and change status to 1(occupied). After the video call, the status can be reset to 0, and the table at roomno:7 , user1 of roomno:7, user2 of roomno:7, can be set to NULL. Its like maintaining tables in a restaurant in a computer.

You can basically develop multiple chatting using 1to1 using a database and php queries, no need to edit any swf code or maintain a complicated server etc.